# IIS - proper permissions to create folders in Root

Tags: iis, permissions

I have a web app that creates a temp. folder in the website root, writes some files into it, and then zips the folder. Everything works fine on my machine. I had to add two extra users to make it work. IUSR and IIS_IUSRS - Both with a full access. The QA persion is reporting that she is getting an error. What I see happening is that no temp. folder is created, however, the zip is altghough with wrong files inside. Can some one please explain is there a difference in permissions to create a file and create a folder?

Thanks

Comment: You might get some basics from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 But you revealed too little about how the actual setup is on the QA machine, so nobody would be able to answer your question I think.

Comment: Not sure what else to provide. The website has Windows Authentication enabled, and  anonymous disabled. The app pool uses default settings.

Comment: If that's what you can provide at this moment, then you seem to have configured the site on QA machine properly. Next, use Process Monitor to see what exactly happens when your web app manipulates the file system. That tool should reveal everything needed.